# why form action empty return to the previous page?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Although I am studying the Java Servlet and JSP from Murach and I have a question about HTML format haha

After submiting a form on index.jsp, the EmailListServlet is called, it does some validation and if everything is ok the thanks.jsp in called.

1. Index.jsp file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Murach's Java Servlets and JSP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Join our email list</h1>
    <p>To join our email list, enter your name and
       email address below.</p>
    <p><i>${message}</i></p>
    <form action="emailList" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">        
        <label class="pad_top">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="${user.email}" 
               required><br>
        <label class="pad_top">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="${user.firstName}" 
               required><br>
        <label class="pad_top">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="${user.lastName}"  
               required><br>        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Join Now" class="margin_left">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2. EmailLisServlet

```html
package murach.email;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import murach.business.User;
import murach.data.UserDB;

public class EmailListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url = "/index.html";
        
        // get current action
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null) {
            action = "join";  // default action
        }

        // perform action and set URL to appropriate page
        if (action.equals("join")) {
            url = "/index.jsp";    // the "join" page
        } 
        else if (action.equals("add")) {
            // get parameters from the request
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            // store data in User object
            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email);

            // validate the parameters
            String message;
            if (UserDB.emailExists(user.getEmail())) {
                message = "This email address already exists.<br>" +
                          "Please enter another email address.";
                url = "/index.jsp";
            }
            else {
                message = "";
                url = "/thanks.jsp";
                UserDB.insert(user);
            }
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
            request.setAttribute("message", message);
        }
        getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);
    }    
}
```

3. thanks.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Murach's Java Servlets and JSP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"/>    
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Thanks for joining our email list</h1>

    <p>Here is the information that you entered:</p>

    <label>Email:</label>
    <span>${user.email}</span><br>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <span>${user.firstName}</span><br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <span>${user.lastName}</span><br>

    <p>To enter another email address, click on the Back 
    button in your browser or the Return button shown 
    below.</p>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="join">
        <input type="submit" value="Return">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The question is I didn't understand why when I submit the form on the thanks.jsp it returns to index.jsp once the action element is empty.
Could you tell me what I'm letting go?

Comment: change your `<input type="submit">` to other type like `button` ,because even if you left `action` blank ,then also data will send to current file.

Comment: Hi Swati. I changed thanks.jsp like you said and nothing happened. I was wondering if a let "action" element  blank it will call the index.jsp by default

Comment: What outcome do you expect? If `action` is null it defaults to `join` and `url` is set to index.jsp. No?

Comment: That was the point, I didn't know that